# XRDP gray screen on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, xfce, xrdp

XRDP use to work for me. one day i woke up and XRDP stop working. I tried everything to fix it. I have bean in every forum on the net for the last couple days, but still nothing. After I login I get a gray screen but don't see the desktop. I even uninstalled XRDP and Xfce4 but still nothing.

These are my settings in `startwm.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -r /etc/default/locale ]; then
 . /etc/default/locale
 export LANG LANGUAGE
fi
. /etc/X11/Xsession
. /usr/bin/startxfce4
```

It use to work when I only had startxfce4. I don't understand why its not working when it always did. I personally don't think `startwm.sh` is the issue here but how do I diagnose my problem?

I know this question has bean repeated many times here, but nothing working for me. Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/603314/gray-screen-when-i-try-to-remote-desktop-to-ubuntu

Comment: edit your question with outtput of startwm.sh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general if you have grey screen through xRDP is either you are using an unsupported desktop environment or you have a typo in your ~/.xession or startwm.sh file.

You have to configure your linux machine to tell him which desktop environment will be used when connecting through xrdp.  You specify this information by either issuing the following command

**> echo xfce-session > ~/.xsession**

If you use this approach, and you have multiple users that needs to use the xRDP, each user will need to login locally on the Ubuntu machine and execute this command

IF you have multiple users that will need to use the XRDP solution, a better option is to let the system automatically create the file. To achieve this,you will add the following line  **echo xfce-session ~/.xsession**  in the startwm.sh file (after the fi line)

Your file will look like this :

> > if [ -r /etc/default/locale ];  then 
> >         . /etc/default/locale
> >           export LANG LANGUAGE
> >         fi
>
> ```
>   #Add this line in the file     
>   echo xfce-session > ~/.xsession
> ```
>
> . /etc/X11/Xsession

Restart your system and give it a try and should be good to go...

Note : You can use mate-desktop as alternate desktop if you do not want to use xfce.

**Detailed description on how to have xrdp working with xfce can be found [here](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=5305)**